# AWS EC2 replacement instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, maintenance

I've inherited our AWS management duties for the time being and I've received a notice from AWS about some of our instances needing regular maintenance. The EC2 instances are pretty primary, a proxy server and a WordPress install.

From the email it says:

> Additional information about maintenance events, including how to migrate to replacement instances, can be found at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html.

I understand the *concept*, but not exactly sure how to accomplish such a task. The proxy instance sits on an Elastic IP, but the WP install does not. The maintenance window is definitely off-hours, but I'd still like to know how to do it.

Can I create an AMI of each and relaunch a new instance based on their respective AMI? I assume for the proxy with the EIP I can reassociate that newly created instance.

I'm not sure how to best accomplish the WP install instance.

I would love some insight into this new realm.

Thanks!

Comment: I"m not sure what you're asking here. Are you attempting to perform some maintenance yourself, or provide some backup system to kick in when maintenance happens, or some third option?

Comment: Trying to follow Amazon's suggestion of migrating the instances that need maintenance to a replacement versions.

Comment: Creating AMIs for each instance then starting new instances by using the AMIs is enough. but you may want to keep your ip addresses. Actually amazon replaces it's host machines as XEN hosts time to time (or maybe regularly, can't be sure right now)  new instances won't use any host that is scheduled to be replaced. so recreating them is enough.

Comment: @risyasin Would you mind elaborating a little bit more on your note about the IP address. That is one of my concerns about the proxy which is on an EIP. And won't recreating a new AMI assign a new IP for each (proxy and WP install)?

Comment: I meant do not release ip addresses that you already using. you can re-associate the existing Elastic ips to new instances. Just go to network menu in EC2 web. choose ip address then re-associate it. Check if everything works. to be sure stop web server in old wordpress instance.

Comment: You have left out a lot of pertinent information... VPC or EC2-Classic?  EBS or Instance Store?  What kind of maintenance event is pending?

Comment: Is the maintenance a reboot, or an instance-stop/retirement?  That can have bearing on your course of action.

Comment: We are using EC2-Classic and is EBS. Is there a way to not lose the IP address of an instance that is not using EIP? Both the proxy and WP install are schedule for a reboot - not retirement.